Understanding Supply Voltages for Inverting Amplifier
I am trying to build an inverted summing amplifier that will sum the result of four AC signals and I would like a bit of clarification when it comes to figuring out the supply voltage for the amplifier. For context, I'm using a OPA2333P and prior to the summing circuit component, the signals that I send to it have been AC coupled. After the signals have been summed, they will be sent to an ADC to process the signal.
From what I understand, you would need to provide both a positive and negative voltage for the amplifier because of how the signal will oscillate between positive and negative values. The part I am confused about are the actual values for positive and negative voltage you would need to provide. Would the values of -V and +V just be the range of the AC signals you expect to receive? If not, then how exactly do you go about determining the supply voltage for the amplifier?

If the signals are AC coupled, you don't need a negative supply. Just define the voltage levels of your signals and output to be used.

For an inverting amplifier, it may depend more on what you want to output, than what you want to input.

The valid input voltage range is specified as the common-mode voltage range. For this opamp it slightly exceeds the power supply inputs. This is often called rail-to-rail inputs. Many opamps have a smaller range than this, especially at the high end.


You are mistaken if you believe that the ADC can work with negative input potentials. It cannot; if the power supply potentials to the ADC are 0V and +5V, then its inputs must never fall outside that same range, 0V to 5V. The datasheet may give the impression that negative inputs are OK, but if you read carefully, you will find that such claims are referring to "differential mode" inputs, where the ADC subtracts two positive inputs to obtain an effective "negative" input value.
The OPA2333 is unusually good, in that both inputs and output are "rail to rail". This permits you to power the op-amp from the same supply as the ADC, limiting its output to the same range of potentials tolerable by the ADC.
Doing this though requires you to "bias" the op-amp output to some potential between the supply potentials, ideally mid-way. This can be achieved with a resistor potential divider.
You mentioned that the source signals to be summed are all AC-coupled, presumably using capacitors. If that's the case, then the whole design becomes trivially simple:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This operates from a single +5V supply, and as long as the ADC is also powered from +5V, then this op-amp is physically incapable of driving the ADC input outside its acceptable 0V to 5V range. The permanent +2.5V offset can be compensated for (removed) in software, or you can use the differential mode of the ADS1115 to do that for you:

simulate this circuit
Interestingly, if you swap A0 and A1 inputs, the ADC will inherently "un-invert" the inverting nature of the summing amplifier. You can do some funky stuff with differential inputs.

Sorry if it sounds like I'm just repeating what you said, but just to make sure I understand this correctly, we need to bias the op-amp output so that the oscillating signal doesn't produce a negative value, which the ADC can't outright accept. This means that +2.5V acts sort of like a virtual ground(?) in this case, right? And since source signals are AC-coupled, should I not really care about the input voltage going into the negative terminal or should I expect it to be in the range of 2.5V - 7.5V?

And about the second circuit, do you mind explaining why it un-inverts? Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly, that would make it seem like a non-inverting summing amplifier, but without all the hassle that comes with the circuit itself

@bimmui You can't get +7.5V out of anything here. OUT will oscillate above and below +2.5V, up to +5V max and down to 0V min, centered at +2.5V, due to the +2.5V bias. The second circuit doesn't un-invert, the ADC does. The ADC (in differential mode) performs $V_{A0}-V_{A1}$ (check the datasheet, I may have got that the wrong way around), so if you connect +2.5V to A0 and OUT to A1, that becomes $+2.5V-V_{OUT}$, another "inversion".

AC-coupled signals don't require any particular voltages of the
receiving circuitry, but the chosen ADC operates on '2 to 5.5V'
power, which implies that no higher ADC input voltages need be considered.
The classical way to sum signals is to use an operational amplifier in
inverting configuration, and let AC currents into the pseudo-ground (-)
input terminal through matched resistors.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The remaining problem is to estimate the range of the input sum current,
which will be on the order of four times the peak AC voltages divided by the (here, 10k ohms) resistances, and ensure that the feedback through
R5 can balance that.
The LM358 is good for inputs in the 0 to 3V range when powered by +5V and
ground; check the data sheet for both input and output range limits of
the OPA2333, but don't try to USE that full range; data captured at the limits of measurement are untrustworthy.   Any ADC also has input range
limits to be avoided.

When using current sources at the inputs, R1, R2, R3 and R4 are not required. This is confusing since OP never said the signals were currents. Presumably the inputs are voltages, in which case those resistors are necessary.
